# Extract Audio from Youtube

Tags: ios, youtube

I want to extract the audio from youtube. I get the [audio URL](http://r16---sn-ab5e6m7s.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?upn=r2NYhGLwjI8&mm=31&mv=m&mt=1424947679&ms=au&signature=E5F25D6A50DB07A30EDD5475E18821E391EDB1D9.ECE2651E3E3896317B6058E5539DA16F3D733E62&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cusequic%2Cexpire&fexp=905657%2C907263%2C912154%2C924630%2C927622%2C934947%2C9406164%2C9406523%2C9406931%2C942658%2C943917%2C947225%2C947240%2C948124%2C951703%2C952302%2C952605%2C952612%2C952620%2C952901%2C955301%2C957201%2C959701&usequic=no&ip=63.141.217.85&clen=552691&keepalive=yes&id=o-AGSvRnABates-XNs5t76ACzlxtFhwjAfB8ey9M2ltB5f&nh=EAI&gir=yes&source=youtube&dur=46.439&pl=24&initcwndbps=1005000&itag=140&ipbits=0&sver=3&lmt=1390762577085509&expire=1424969307&key=yt5&mime=audio%2Fmp4) from the youtube watch page inside **adaptive_fmts** parameter. 
I am downloading audio from this url on iOS 7 and iOS 8 using `NSURLConnection`

```
 NSURLRequest * audioRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlString]];
 audioConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: audioRequest delegate: self];
```

But the problem is the downloaded file is playing on iOS8 with double   duration compared to original file but not playing on iOS7. For playing audio I am using this code

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audio_1" ofType:@"m4a"];
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playBackFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];
moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 200);
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
```

I am getting info of the audio file using terminal

```
> File:          filepath File type ID:   mp4f Num Tracks:     1
> ---- Data format:     2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'aac ' (0x00000000) 0 bits/channel, 0 bytes/packet, 1024 frames/packet, 0 bytes/frame
> Channel layout: Stereo (L R) estimated duration: 180.464036 sec audio
> bytes: 0 audio packets: 7774 bit rate: 0 bits per second packet size
> upper bound: 0 maximum packet size: 0 audio data file offset: 3544 not
> optimized audio 7958464 valid frames + 2112 priming + 0 remainder =
> 7960576 format list: [ 0] format:   2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'aac '
> (0x00000000) 0 bits/channel, 0 bytes/packet, 1024 frames/packet, 0
> bytes/frame Channel layout: Stereo (L R)
```

Showing bit rate and audio bites zero. I am stuck here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pretty sure that this sort of thing is specifically against youtube's terms of service.

Comment: Yes, I know but I am doing this for learning purpose. The problem is why its played on iOS8 and not on iOS7